# writing a nested sql query and getting bad data

Tags: sql

I am having an issue.  I am trying to make 1 query do a couple of things I am needing done.
The current query is below...

```
  Select RiderNumber, BikeNumber, RidesThatCount, NumberOfRides, Ridelevel 
    from tblMinimumRides  
   where (BikeNumber in  
              (Select  BikeNumber from tbleveryride group by BikeNumber, RideLevel 
                                      having count( distinct judge) > 4
              ) 
           and BikeNumber in 
              (  Select BikeNumber 
                   from tbleveryride 
               group by BikeNumber, ridelevel 
                 having count( distinct Shows) > 4)
               ) 
             order by RiderNumber, BikeNumber
```

I am needing the query to pull RiderNumber, BikeNumber, RidesThatCount, NumberOfRides, Ridelevel fields from the tblMinimumRides where the Bike/Rider/Level have been seen by > 4 judges from the tblEveryRide and the Bike/Rider/Level have been seen in > 4 shows in tblEveryRide table.
The current method kind of works but isn't completely correct if the Rider and Bike are in more than 1 levels and didn't have enough shows at one of the levels.  The issue is the Rider has enough judges at lvl 9 on 2 different bikes. At lvl 8, there isn't enough shows but it is pulling through as good.  I could break this up into different steps, but would prefer to not.

Comment: Could you include the schema for both tables? Is `RiderNumber` also part of `tblEveryRide`, or just in `tblMinimumRides`?

Comment: Why do you have 2 inner selects to the same table?  Couldn't you just join to the table once, since you are grouping on the same columns. 
Also, plz include schema.

Comment: tblMinimumRides: (RiderNumber, BikeNumber, RidesThatCount, NumberOfRides, Ridelevel)
tbleveryride: (RiderNumber, BikeNumber, Shows, Judge, Ridelevel)
I can make that one query, but the issue still is that the Ridelevel isn't being taken into consideration.